# Autoajustar el tamaño de la fuente de un input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, entrada

Necesito crear una función que cuando el valor de un `<input type="text">` sea mayor que su ancho, disminuya el `font-size` del input para que quepa todo el contenido (todo ello dinámicamente).

No quiero usar plugins ya creados y no puedo usar `max-length`, `size`, etc de `HTML`.

¿Alguien sabe cómo podría hacerlo?

```
<input type="text" class="nombre" />
```

Comment: Podrías añadir qué has intentado y te ha fallado.

Comment: No sería mejor ajustar el ancho del input en vez del tamaño de su fuente? Ya que si pones un texto más o menos largo la letra sería casi imposible de leer...

Comment: Te recomiendo que reconsideres la propuesta, ya que es poco practico y queda horrible la solución. Te lo digo por que tengo el código del que necesitas, pero es poco practico.

Comment: y si lo ves desde un movil? no se podra leer la letra..,por qué quieres hacer esto? tal vez exista una alternativa mas practica y con mejores resultados si conocemos tus intenciones

Comment: Te he dejado un ejemplo que hace lo que quieres, Saludos!! ;))..

Answer (score 1):

una forma sencilla es usando [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) y usar [`measureText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) para obtener dimensiones del texto como ancho y alto.

**Ejemplo**

```js
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.input'))
inputs.forEach(input => (
  input.addEventListener('input', e => {
    const { family, size, weight, style } = getFontStyle(input)
    const fontStyle = `${style} ${size} ${family}`
    const len = getStringWidth(input.value, fontStyle)
    const width = input.clientWidth
    if (len > width) {
      const exp = new RegExp(/\d+/)
      input.style.fontSize = (Number(size.match(exp)[0]) - 1) + 'px'
    }
  })
))

function getStringWidth(str, fontStyle) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  context.font = fontStyle
  const metrics = context.measureText(str);
  return metrics.width
}

function getFontStyle(el) {
  const computed = getComputedStyle(el, null)
  const family = el.style.fontFamily || computed.getPropertyValue('font-family')
  const size = el.style.fontSize || computed.getPropertyValue('font-size')
  const weight = el.style.fontWeight || computed.getPropertyValue('font-weight')
  const style = el.style.fontStyle || computed.getPropertyValue('font-style')
  return { family, size, weight, style }
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06) inset;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 200px;
}
.input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 188, 255, .8);
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your name" />
```

En el ejemplo que he puesto, primero se intenta obtener los estilos de fuente directamente del elemento y, en caso no existan, se obtiene de forma computada (que están añadidos mediante [css](/questions/tagged/css)). Esto es importante porque una vez que el texto sobrepasa el ancho de la caja de texto (debe tener un ancho fijo) se disminuye la fuente en `1px` y se añade directamente sobre el elemento mediante el atributo `style`. Como observación, debes usar `clientWidth` ya que si usas `offsetWidth` tomarías el ancho **total** de la caja de texto, lo que incluye su padding.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar algo asi :

```js
function fontSizeInput(){
    var input = document.getElementById("fname");
    //console.log(input.value.length);
    var initialSize = 25 - input.value.length;
    initialSize = initialSize <= 10 ? 10:initialSize;
    input.style.fontSize = initialSize + "px";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="fontSizeInput()">
```

Se toma el valor inicial del input, que es 0 y se establece una cantidad que en este caso es 25. Cuando el largo del valor del input es menor o igual a 10. El valor siempre sera 10. Mientras sea mayor seguira tomando el resultado de la resta de `25 - input.length`. Finalmente se carga al style del input el fontsize de ese valor `initialSize`

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente ejemplo te muestra como cambiar el tamaño de la fuente mientras escribes para adaptarlo al tamaño de la caja del `input`.

Ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input")
.forEach(function(i) {
 i.addEventListener("keyup",compressInput)
});
function compressInput(event) {
 var e = event.target;
 if (!e.style.width) {
  e.style.width  = e.offsetWidth  + "px";   // Fija el Tamaño del Ancho 
  e.style.height = e.offsetHeight + "px";   // Fija el Tamaño del Alto
  e.dataset.fontSize = fontSize(e);    // Determina el tamaño de la Fuente
 }
 var f = e.dataset.fontSize * (e.value.length + 1) / 2;
 e.style.fontSize = (f > e.offsetWidth)
  ? e.offsetWidth / (e.value.length + 1) * 2 + "px"
  : e.dataset.fontSize + "px";
}

// Calcula el Tamaño de la Fuente
function fontSize(e) {
 var ex = /font\-size:[\s+]?(\d+)px/i;
 var fontSize = ex.exec(e.style.cssText);
 if (fontSize == null) {
  CLASS: {
   for(var x=0; x<e.classList.length; x++) {
    var css = e.classList[x];
    for(var y=0; y<document.styleSheets.length; y++) {
     var sheet = document.styleSheets[y].cssRules;
     for(var z=0; z<sheet.length; z++) {
      if(sheet[z].selectorText == "."+css) {
       ex = /[\s+]?(\d+)px/ig;
       fontSize = ex.exec(sheet[z].style.fontSize);
       break CLASS;
 }}}}}}
 if(fontSize == null)
  fontSize = "12";
 else
  fontSize = fontSize[1];

 return fontSize;
}
```

```css
.font-size-18 {
 font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<p>fontSize 12px (by Default)<br>
<input type="text"></p>

<p>fontSize 18px (by Class)<br>
<input type="text" class="font-size-18"></p>

<p>fontSize 24px (by Style)<br>
<input type="text" style="font-size:24px"></p>
```

Espero esto te sirva, Saludos!! ;))...